# Need help proving discontinuity of function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

$$ f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$$
$$ 
f(x, y) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if }(x, y) = (0, 0) \\
\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}, & \text{otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$

My plan was to substitute y as in: $$y^2=mx$$ where $y\to 0$ as $x\to 0$.

Then this would result in  $f(x,y)=\dfrac{m}{m^2+1}$ which has different values for different values of $m$. Does this work to prove that f(x, y) is not continuous at (0, 0)?

Comment: Yes, this works

Comment: Remark also $$ f\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$ which does not tend to $f(0,0)$

Comment: Isnt it n instead of 1/2?

Comment: @Atmos That's a special case of $y^2=mx$, with $m=1$.
@ alex403 It is $\frac12$

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right my bad.